# How can mechanical processes designed to create demigods lead to less desirable results?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, genetic-engineering

Mana is the energy and life force of an individual, as well as serve as a unique signature. An anathame is a weapon infused with the power of a god, in which only their mortal descendants can used. To create one, a god must infuse his mana into the weapons, implanting it with a divine lock. When a demigod from his mortal line uses it, their Mana inherited from their god-parent will unlock it with their Mana, giving them access to it's abilities. All others who attempt to use it will be destroyed.

Many gods are promiscuous in the mortal realm, allowing for potential demigods to inhabit the earth. I have managed to  get my hands on a God's essence ( don't ask how) with a plan to create numerous demigods to create an army under my control using artificial fertilization. This mechanical process is more efficient and less time consuming, as would speed up the rate of demigods inhabiting the plane. However, the children produced from this method turn out to be regular humans with no divine Mana whatsoever. This undermines the entire plan, as it prevents then using using the stockpile of anathame that I have gathered.

A God's essence is infused with his Mana, and is the main contributor to the amount of demigods on the mortal realm. What would have prevented more efficient and artificial methods from achieving the same result ?

Comment: I'm curious how you expect this to be answered with facts and citations rather than people making up something that is narratively interesting. Remember that questions need to be specific enough that there should be an easy way to assess the quality of answers. If people can just make anything up it's not a good fit for this site. In fact we used to have a special close reason just for questions like that called idea generation.

Comment: Well, it is very obvious that you laid your hands on the wrong material. It is not the god's essence which makes demigods, it is his sperm. A remedial course in how mortal women make babies might be in order.

Comment: Poor recording-keeping at the sperm bank.

Comment: These days everything is labelled as 'opinion-based'... sigh... On a more productive note, what exactly is god's essence?  How is it associated with the number of demigods in the mortal realm?

Answer (score 2):

1. God did it

The gods aren't thrilled About someone else other than them making army of demigods Well technically not Breaking any sort of divine law They don't feel good about it so so they decide to alter them draw them so that they have no access to their powers.

2. Is magic and technology don't mix.

Attempting to study magic like a scientific process makes a thing unmagical somehow.

3. Is not just the act of sex but a conscious choice on the part of a God to make a demigod.  Without the God make a free choice to make one then you only have a regular human.

Comment: What is the point of answering this question?

Comment: Honestly boredom  And why not